# with an expression on your face that shows dislike and a lack of respect

Tags: grammar

> sneer
>
> 1 : to smile or laugh at someone or something **with an expression on your face that shows dislike and a lack of respect**

[Source](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/sneer)

---

1. I wonder if "**an expression on your face that shows dislike and a lack of respect**" acts as a noun.
2. I wonder if "**an expression on your face that shows dislike and a lack of respect**" is the object of the preposition "**with**".

Comment: Yes, it is. It's a long one, huh?

Comment: Yes, and more than that, that phrase *actually is a noun phrase* because the head of that phrase, "expression" is a noun. We only use "acting as" when there's some other part of speech, like a verb or a clause, doing the job of a noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In grammar, saying that something "acts like a noun" is pretty vague. (Actual nouns [can "act like" adjectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), for example, so such terminology can be confusing.)

"An expression on your face that shows dislike and a lack of respect" might be called a "[noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase)" (or "nominal phrase", etc.). Yes, it functions as an object (some would say complement) of the preposition "with".

Comment: How do you mean "acts like a noun" is vague? To me it's equivalent to, "functions as a noun", which is pretty common in both ESL and linguistics.

Comment: @gotube But how does a noun function? It can "function as" an adjective, adverb, verb, etc., and the reverse is true, too. So some parts of speech are "functioning as" completely different parts of speech. Furthermore, the same words are used to describe both parts of speech and functions, which are distinct properties. This can easily confuse native speakers to say nothing of people trying to learn the language. (I've seen this confusion arise many times with gerunds, especially.)

Comment: We must be talking past each other. To me, this question is really basic and I don't know how to make myself clearer without explaining, for instance, what an actual noun is, and how something that's not an actual noun, like a clause, can do the things a real noun does without confusing anyone into thinking the clause is actually a real noun. That shouldn't be necessary because I know you know your stuff.

Comment: @gotube Yeah, we may just be talking past each other. I certainly *usually* understand when people say "acts as a noun", but I do think that there's a potential for misunderstanding, so I suppose it's just a matter of preference for different terminology (as so many issues in English are!).

Comment: I've added a comment to the question. Does it bring us closer to mutual understanding?

Comment: @gotube Well, we may not agree entirely on this issue, but I think we're mostly simpatico. :)